# jQuery: button which is created have effect like first button

Tags: jquery

I have some code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).after('<button>click</button>');
});
```

And button:

```
<button>click</button>
```

When I click **first button**, a button is created.Then I click on **second button**,nothing happen istead of another **click** is created.And **only** when I click on my `first button`, I will make a button
How can do to make **all the button**'ll be able create another buttons, not just first button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give same CLASS to all buttons.

if you are using jquery < 1.9 V use .live()

if you are using jquery >= 1.9 V use .on()

```
$(CLASS).live('click', function() {

     // SOME ACTION

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Event Delegation using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**. I would suggest you to use a *class name for the buttons so that you bind events and delegate only to those buttons as 'button' selector is too generic*.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).after('<button>click</button>');
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GVZbA/)

#### Html

```
<button class="addBtn">Add</button>
```

#### Script

```
$(document).on('click', '.addBtn', function(){
  $(this).after('<button class="addBtn">click</button>');
});
```

When you just bind a click event, it will be only bound to the existing DOM elements, so you want to bind the event to the parent element (ex:- i have used document but you can use the container that already exists like a div or something), and later any elements you add with the same selector with that container will have the event available by delegation.

> *From Jquery Docs*
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Also, adding the event delegation `.on()` on the closest parent to the target element will improve your script's performance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
   $(this).after('<button>click</button>');
});
```

Because `.on` allow us to have event assigned to DOM which are added later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click',"button",function(){
  $(this).after('<button>click</button>');
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/on